# Pattern matching and RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching, rdd

I have a very simple (n00b) question but I'm somehow stuck. I'm trying to read a set of files in Spark with `wholeTextFiles` and want to return an `RDD[LogEntry]`, where `LogEntry` is just a case class. I want to end up with an RDD of valid entries and I need to use a regular expression to extract the parameters for my case class. When an entry is not valid I do not want the extractor logic to fail but simply write an entry in a log. For that I use LazyLogging.

```
object LogProcessors extends LazyLogging {

  def extractLogs(sc: SparkContext, path: String, numPartitions: Int = 5): RDD[Option[CleaningLogEntry]] = {

    val pattern = "<some pattern>".r

    val logs = sc.wholeTextFiles(path, numPartitions)
    val entries = logs.map(fileContent => {
      val file = fileContent._1
      val content = fileContent._2
      content.split("\\r?\\n").map(line => line match {
        case pattern(dt, ev, seq) => Some(LogEntry(<...>))
        case _ => logger.error(s"Cannot parse $file: $line"); None
      })
    })
```

That gives me an `RDD[Array[Option[LogEntry]]]`. Is there a neat way to end up with an RDD of the `LogEntry`s? I'm somehow missing it.

I was thinking about using `Try` instead, but I'm not sure if that's any better.

Thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the signature of the final `RDD` to be `RDD[LongEntry]` or `RDD[Array[LogEntry]]` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get rid of the `Array` - simply replace the `map` command with `flatMap` - flatMap will treat a result of type `Traversable[T]` for each record as separate records of type `T`.
2. To get rid of the `Option` - `collect` only the successful ones: `entries.collect { case Some(entry) => entry }`. 
   Note that this `collect(p: PartialFunction)` overload (which performs something equivelant to a `map` and a `filter` combined) is very different from `collect()` (which sends all data to the driver).

Altogether, this would be something like:

```
def extractLogs(sc: SparkContext, path: String, numPartitions: Int = 5): RDD[CleaningLogEntry] = {

  val pattern = "<some pattern>".r

  val logs = sc.wholeTextFiles(path, numPartitions)
  val entries = logs.flatMap(fileContent => {
    val file = fileContent._1
    val content = fileContent._2
    content.split("\\r?\\n").map(line => line match {
      case pattern(dt, ev, seq) => Some(LogEntry(<...>))
      case _ => logger.error(s"Cannot parse $file: $line"); None
    })
  })

  entries.collect { case Some(entry) => entry }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I knew it was simple but somehow my brain is not cooperating today. Is there a difference between `entries.collect()` (as in your solution) and `entries.flatMap(e => e)`?

Comment: I believe there isn't - flatMap works because Option is implicitly converted to `Seq` with 0 or 1 records, and then flatMap just takes these records if they exist.. so I guess the two will function exactly the same.